# Date differnce not giving correct in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get differnce between 2 date in minuts but i tried from lots of method but not getting real difference

I tried

```
var punchIn = "Fri Apr 21 2017 10:57:11 GMT+0530 (IST)";

var punchOut ="Fri Apr 21 2017 13:19:50 GMT+0530 (IST)";



 var startDate = new Date(punchIn);
 var endDate = new Date(punchOut);
 var workingHours = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
```

> (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) = 8559000 convert it into
>   hours it gives 
>   2.3775

But it should be 2 hours 22 minutes ..

Comment: Your hours are in decimal if you want minutes multiply the part after the coma by 60.  so: 0.3775h * 60 gives 22.65min the result you want.

Comment: This is really just a simple math question.

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper and work out the math ... then code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var workingHours = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);` this perfectly converts it to minutes, but when you do another `* 60` it puts the time into hours yes. But there's a twist. Those 0.3775 are those 22 minutes. Just because its converted to hours and it works up to 0.9 even, but those are the minutes, just converted behind the decimal. Because there is no time element.

Maybe you could create another Date object over the `var workingHours = new Date ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60));` like this or something, but thats for you to figure out.

EDIT:

```js
var punchIn = "Fri Apr 21 2017 10:57:11 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var punchOut ="Fri Apr 21 2017 13:19:50 GMT+0530 (IST)";
   
var startDate = new Date(punchIn);
var endDate = new Date(punchOut);
   
var millis = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());

var second = (millis / 1000) % 60;
var minute = Math.floor(millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
var hour = Math.floor(millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
   
var time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
   
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML += time;
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, C, E, T, TimeSpan; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){

// Maybe you'll learn something here
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
TimeSpan = function(startDate, endDate){
  var workingHours = (endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime())/3600000;
  this.hours = Math.floor(workingHours);
  var ml = (workingHours-this.hours).toString().length-2, workingMinutes = (workingHours*Math.pow(10, ml)-this.hours*Math.pow(10, ml))*60/Math.pow(10, ml);
  this.minutes = Math.floor(workingMinutes);
  var sl = (workingMinutes-this.minutes).toString().length-2;
  this.seconds = Math.round((workingMinutes*Math.pow(10, sl)-this.minutes*Math.pow(10, sl))*60/Math.pow(10, sl));
}
var form = E('form');
form.addEventListener('sumbit', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
var start = E('start'), stop = E('stop'), btn = E('btn');
start.value = 'Fri Apr 21 2017 10:57:11 GMT+0530 (IST)';
stop.value = 'Fri Apr 21 2017 13:19:50 GMT+0530 (IST)';
function displaySpan(){
 var span = new TimeSpan(new Date(start.value), new Date(stop.value));
 E('output').innerHTML = 'Hours: '+span.hours+'<br />Minutes: '+span.minutes+'<br />Seconds: '+span.seconds;
}
btn.addEventListener('click', displaySpan);
var els = form.elements;
for(var i=0,fe,l=els.length; i<l; i++){
  fe = els[i];
  fe.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode === 13)displaySpan();
  });
}

});
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#form{
  width:600px; height:50px; background:green; color:#fff; padding:10px;
}
#form>label{
  width:40px;
}
#form>label,#form>input[type=text]{
  display:block; float:left;
}
#form>input[type=text]{
  width:250px; margin-bottom:10px;
}
#form>#start{
  margin-right:7px;
}
#form>#btn{
  display:block; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>TimeSpan</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form'>
      <label for='start'>Start:</label><input id='start' name='start' type='text' />
      <label for='stop'>Stop:</label><input id='stop' name='stop' type='text' />
      <input id='btn' type='button' value='TimeSpan' />
    </form>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that JavaScript has trouble with decimals. Solution is to make them whole numbers by multiplying by powers of 10 then dividing by the same.

Answer (score -1):

10:57:11 + 2 hours 22 minutes = 13:19:11 not 13:19:50

Also 2.3775 hours is 120 minutes + (60 * 0.3775) minutes = 22.65 minutes.

So the calculations are correct, you're missing the 0.65 minute (39 seconds)

You can calculate the extra seconds with `(8559000 / 1000) mod 60`

```
var total = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
var seconds = total % 60;
total = total - seconds; // Floor to the minutes.

Now the total contains exactly 2:22 minutes (in seconds)
```

Comment: this is nothing more than a comment and doesn't help OP get expected results

Comment: The problem is the additional seconds, so added code example how to calculate the additional seconds.

Comment: The missing seconds really aren't the issue here. The OP's question was about taking a number of milliseconds (8559000) and converting it to hours and minutes, so telling them how to get the result in seconds doesn't answer the question (though the key point about 60 * 0.3775 *is* buried in your answer).